# Reason for inconsistent behavior of single quotes during BASH parameter expansion?

Tags: bash, shell, quotes, quoting, parameter-expansion

When using BASH [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), string that variable expands into can be quoted/escaped, which works fine, except when the single quotes are used and the whole variable is escaped in double quotes:

```
$ echo "${var:-\\a}"
\a # ok
$ echo "${var:-"\\a"}"
\a # ok
$ echo "${var:-$'\\a'}"
\a # ok
$ echo "${var:-'\a'}"
'\a' # wtf?
```

Interestingly, `$' '` quotes work normally, while `' '` don't. Single quotes start working correctly if the variable itself is not quoted:

```
$ echo ${var:-'\a'}
\a
```

But, that can lead to other issues if `$var` itself contains whitespace characters.

Is there any good reason for this inconsistency?

Comment: Single quotes inside double quotes are preserved literally. `echo "'foobar'"` preserves the `'`, but `echo ""foobar""` doesn't

Comment: @Inian in your example, `foobar` itself would be unquoted. Why, then, is the output of `var2=*; echo "${var:-"$var2"}"` just `*`, whereas the output of `echo ""*""` is the glob expansion to all files?

Comment: [This paragraph](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#quote_nesting) seems to be looking at similar problems.

Comment: Quotes inside parameter expansions are tricky. `bash` itself (sometime after 4.0 came out) changed how it treats them to comply with a POSIX ruling.

Comment: @chepner I tried to find such a change in the release notes, but I wasn't able to find anything. I remember that I saw something related to it once, though.

Comment: I think this is covered by POSIX interpretation 221 (which Chet Ramey cited when I asked about a similar quotes-within-quotes construction a few years ago), although I can't seem to find that on-line anywhere.

Comment: n.b. You missed `"${var:-\a}"` also yielding `\a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the most relevant quote from the source code (`y.tab.c`):

```
  /* Based on which dolstate is currently in (param, op, or word),
     decide what the op is.  We're really only concerned if it's % or
     #, so we can turn on a flag that says whether or not we should
     treat single quotes as special when inside a double-quoted
     ${...}. This logic must agree with subst.c:extract_dollar_brace_string
     since they share the same defines. */
  /* FLAG POSIX INTERP 221 */

  [...]

  /* The big hammer.  Single quotes aren't special in double quotes.  The
     problem is that Posix used to say the single quotes are semi-special:
     within a double-quoted ${...} construct "an even number of
     unescaped double-quotes or single-quotes, if any, shall occur." */
  /* This was changed in Austin Group Interp 221 */
```

It's not exactly clear to me *why* single quotes aren't special, but it seems like a conscious choice made after long (and I've been told contentious) debate preceding the change. But the fact is (if I am summarizing this correctly), single quotes here are just regular characters, not syntactic quotes, and are treated literally.

Comment: Interesting. Not really an explanation, but at least that is the reason. I guess I'll have to accept it.